# thermald - AMD Phenom II 1035T X6 - how to configure XML?

Tags: 15.04, asus, fan, temperature, amd-processor

I have a six core AMD CPU - AMD Phenom II 1035T X6 on an ASUS M4A88-t motherboard and I am aware that the CPU temp needs to be kept under 70°C...

However, the fan never seems to come on to regulate the temperature. I am aware of `thermald` and that `thermald.conf` controls this, but apparently there is only an example/generic/non-functional XML conf file present in my Ubuntu 15.04. I have read through what I could find on the web but still don't know what specifics are needed to edit this file with.

[Here is my `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml`](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/12719340/) and [here is my `sensors` output](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/12719360/)

Do I need to update GRUB? Is there an enable to add to grub? What sensors/cooling zones/thermal zones do I have, how to know?

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/12719340/

Comment: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/12719360/

Comment: Is there any simple way to just set the cpu fan to max?

Comment: Sorry for giving you the wrong spot for `thermald-conf.xml`, but you seem to have figured it out!  **;-)** Please delete all other comments as they've been incorporated into your question.  Analysing and answering now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Your system is correctly configured and you don't need to do anything...

**Long answer:**

1. Your `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml` contains 2 sections: the actual configuration (lines 6 to 43 in the file on your machine, lines 11 to 48 in your paste) and an example configuration (all the following lines).  Furthermore, your thermal settings are set for maximum performance, not for maximum cooling.

   For more information on the exotic paramaters, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

   ```
    man thermal-conf.xml
   ```
2. Your `sensors` output shows that the CPU fan is running at 3479 rotations per minute (that's 86 rotations per second!) so the CPU fan is working correctly!  You're probably not hearing much as that is inside your tower (assuming a tower model as you're not hearing anything) and it's very probably a super-silent one keeping the CPU T° below the threshold of 95°C.

   Neither the chassis nor the power fan is running *at all* as the current T° is 44°C, below the 45°C high mark of the motherboard and way below the 75°C critical T°.

#### So the easiest of answers: Don't do anything!

3. Extra freebie: **You don't need to** but *if you're really paranoid about cooling*, change `<Preference>PERFORMANCE</Preference>` to `<Preference>QUIET</Preference>`...

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: And before I forget: I didn't add your comment about running the fan at full blast to your original question because you *could* do that, but why should you as that would be the same as letting your car idle at maximum RPM all of the time... (possible, but no advantages and bad for the car)

Comment: Thank you for the help. The reason I am trying to get cooling working properly is that I need to build the Yocto Project software and that is going to take all six cores. If I do that, then I can guarantee that the temperature will soar to over 75C in a few minutes... and Yocto needs hours to build. The fan speed will remain the same however, I know from experience. 

I am under the impression that the AMD spec say that the max temperature for the Phenom II 1035T X6 needs to stay under 70C. If this isn't true, then can someone correct me?

Comment: ...sensors seems to indicate the critical temperature is 95C... I don't know where it gets this from...

Comment: There is a difference between the total motherboard T° and the CPU T°: the CPU can handle much more.   In laptops this is pushed to an extreme: here is mine: `Core 0:       +52.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)` (thanks for the acceptance, favour returned: upvoted answer)

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately installed a liquid cooling system - I'd prefer the peace of mind Running a Yocto project build with 12 tasks going has only gotten the cpu temp to 43C after 15 minutes.

Thanks to Fabby for his help.

Comment: This does not answer the OP.